# Query shared BigQuery dataset with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to extract data from a BigQuery shared dataset. The dataset was shared with me through my gmail account, but I created credentials for my GCS Project. Then, I am having an error since these credentials are unassociated to my gmail account. I need credentials for my gmail account so I can query the shared dataset with Python BigQuery.

I created the client for my Project (but the shared dataset is in another Project):

client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

And then run a query getting this error:

"Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied for table:..."

Comment: You can ask the owner of the table to share the dataset with the email of the service account - or login with your own account (OAuth2) and then the script will use your credentials.

Comment: Thanks! But I would prefer not to ask the owner for new permissions. I'll try with OAuth2